# Code doesn't recognize chromedriver.exe as a file

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So i'm new with python, and got interested with WebDriver and its possible applications. So i've written this just to test that all the necessary libraries are installed.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r'chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

And once i write python3 nameOfCode.py the result is an error as it so often is. The error(s) are

```
macs-MacBook-Pro:Desktop mac$ python3 testSelenium.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testSelenium.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= mac/Desktop/chromedriver.exe)
NameError: name 'mac' is not defined
macs-MacBook-Pro:Desktop mac$ python3 testSelenium.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testSelenium.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= Desktop/chromedriver.exe)
NameError: name 'Desktop' is not defined
macs-MacBook-Pro:Desktop mac$ python3 testSelenium.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testSelenium.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= chromedriver.exe)
NameError: name 'chromedriver' is not defined
macs-MacBook-Pro:Desktop mac$ python3 testSelenium.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver.exe': 'chromedriver.exe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testSelenium.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r'chromedriver.exe')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Sorry if this is much :))
Dario

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run a Windows binary (.exe) on a Mac? That is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The last line says it all...

```
'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

If you are using Windows:

You need to add the location of "chromedriver.exe" to your environment variable named `PATH`. You should be able to find the dialog through the start menu search (search for: environment variables), then find the variable named `PATH` (not case sensitive). If it doesn't exist, create it. The contents of this variable is a list of folder locations separated by semicolons, and the folder containing "chromedriver.exe" needs to be there.

If you're on a Mac: (I don't have one so I can't confirm these methods)

edit "/etc/paths" file to have the location of the executable, or put:

```
PATH="${PATH}:/some/other/directory:/another/place/scripts/live:"

export $PATH
```

somewhere in your *.bash_profile* file

Comment: İ'm using mac, is it still the same?

Comment: It would seem that if you have Chrome in the default location, Selenium should be able to find it without specifying the executable path. It would also seem that you are trying to use a windows program on a mac... there is an OSX specific executable for Chromedriver.

Comment: What if i just add the path code you suggested onto the main file with the google code. Also, how would i restore chrome to its default location?